# How can I iterate through an array over and over again while assigning each of its values to all the svgs in my DOM

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, maps

Sorry if my question is worded poorly. I am a beginner and don't know the proper labels for things.

I am making a map of Japan using d3.js and would like to assign a color to each of the prefectures. The prefectures are each their own svg. I have an array of the hexadecimal values of the colors I want to use and basically want to write a function which assigns the first color of the array to the "fill" property of the first svg, the second to the second and so on. The colors would have to repeat at some point because there are so many prefectures. I am really having a difficult time conceptualizing how to go about this and would love any help! My code is below. I am thinking the code should go right at the bottom of the javascript where I have the ? comment.

Also, the basis for this comes from the "let's make a map" tutorial by Mike Bostock if that helps.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>



</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960;
var height = 1160;

/* list of colors to iterate thru for prefecture color */
var colors = ["#8dd3c7", "#ffffb3", "#bebada", "#fb8072", "#80b1d3",
              "#fdb462", "#b3de69", "#fccde5", "#d9d9d9"];

var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .center([138.3, 39.2])
    .scale(1500);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("width", width);

/* draws the map. try to make a loop in here which uses the data id of
    the prefectures to uses the color list above to differentiate pref*/
d3.json("japanv2.json", function(error, japan) {
  svg.selectAll(".prefecture")
      .data(topojson.feature(japan, japan.objects.prefectures).features)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", function (d) { return "prefecture " + d.id; })
      .attr("d", path)
/*?*/ .attr("fill", 
      }
});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in the attribute:

```
.attr("fill", function(d,i){
    return colors[i%colors.length]
});
```

**What does this snippet do?**

First, the `i` in `function(d,i)` returns the index of each one of your paths. So, if you do this:

```
.attr("fill", function(d,i){
    console.log(i);
    return colors[i%colors.length];
});
```

You're gonna see a bunch on numbers on your console. If you have, let's say, 200 paths, `i` goes from 0 to 199.

Now the modulo operator:

```
x % y
```

It returns the [remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) of the division. So, given that your `colors` is an array with 9 colours, this:

```
i % colors.length
```

Will return this sequence:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1 etc
```

That you can use to get the `colors` value.

PS: in a map, any map, we only need [*4 colours*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem) to avoid any two areas with the same colours having a common border! (unbelievable, I know...)

Comment: I edited *modulus* operator to be *modulo* operator, which is the correct term. Sometimes the divisor is referred to as *modulus* but the operation and its result are commonly known as *modulo*. I have also replaced the link to Microsoft's explanation with one to MDN which phrases it right.

Comment: Thanks! That is an extremely useful explanation!

Answer (score 1):

I've never used D3 before, but keeping track of your place in an array isn't too bad.

I'd start by keeping track of where you are in the array with another variable, maybe set under the `var colors` line.

```
var currentColor = 0;
```

Then when you're changing the prefecture color, you can reference the current place in the array by using:

```
colors[currentColor]
```

After you've done that, you'll want to update your currentColor with:

```
currentColor++;
if (currentColor == colors.length) {
    currentColor = 0;
}
```

This increments the currentColor value +1 and then resets it back to 0 once the last color was used.  That way you can use start back at the beginning color if you have more prefectures.

**UPDATE**

Looking more at your code, I'm thinking that the `colors[currentColor]` I mentioned in my answer would go after the comma in this line:

```
/*?*/ .attr("fill",
```